# Angular application suddenly fails - "JavaScript heap out of memory"

Tags: angular-cli

When doing ng serve using Angular-cli I all of a sudden experience this error. What does this mean and how can I track down the error?

I have been playing with the angular.json file but have not touched the source code at all before this occured.

Can I get more information somehow regarding this error? Some debugging possible?

```
[8472:0000027E1D943100]   199982 ms: Mark-sweep 1244.7 (1484.0) -> 1244.6 (1488.0) MB, 1490.9 / 2.5 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[8472:0000027E1D943100]   201455 ms: Mark-sweep 1244.6 (1488.0) -> 1244.5 (1446.5) MB, 1473.7 / 2.8 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[8472:0000027E1D943100]   202974 ms: Mark-sweep 1244.5 (1446.5) -> 1244.5 (1439.5) MB, 1518.3 / 2.7 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000000F103425879 <JSObject>
    1: push(this=00000396CD788A21 <JSArray[579629]>)
    2: /* anonymous */ [C:\Apache24\htdocs\myproject\node_modules\readdirp\readdirp.js:~177] [pc=0000006E6B5D6C9D](this=000002313C98C2F1 <JSGlobal Object>,err=000000088F582201 <null>,stat=000002E4C4DA0851 <Stats map = 000003BC493C0269>)
    3: /* anonymous */ [C:\Apache24\htdocs\myproject\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:287] [bytecode=...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray
 5: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
 6: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
 7: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
 8: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
 9: v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo::SetScript
10: v8::internal::JSReceiver::class_name
11: v8::internal::SourcePositionTableIterator::Advance
12: v8::internal::SourcePositionTableIterator::Advance
13: 0000006E6B4843C1
```

Comment: Wich version of angular cli?

Comment: Seems to be known issue. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618#issuecomment-431653364

Comment: Hi, version of Angular CLI is 6.2.5
Angular 6.1.10

Answer (score 0):

In the old Angular cli it happens on large codebase ... one possible fix was to do a little hack on the ngc.cmd file (on wondows) and  increase the

```
--max_old_space_size=8192
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Tried that, result is the same. Can I increase further maybe?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found the reason, in the angular.json file my "assetts" part looks like below, with a reference to an external file that I would like to include in the build. When doing "ng serve" this seems to be a problem.

My solution is to exclude this part during development and put it back when building to production.

Is there a way to specify that this asset will only be included when doing 
"build --prod"?

```
"assets": [
              "src/.htaccess",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/api",
              "src/app/img",

  {"input": "C:/apache/htdocs/api",
   "glob": "apiconfig.php",
   "output": "apiconfig" }
]
```